# Get OpenCV2.1 to run in windows using eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to get OpenCV2.1 to run on my windows machine. Here is what I have done so far:

- Installed MinGW using MinGW-get-inst
- Installed Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express
- Installed OpenCV-2.1.0-win32-vs2008.exe downloaded from OpenCV's website
- Installed Eclipse

Then to test everything, I created a new project, and:

- Configured Eclipse to include "C:\OpenCV2.1\include\opencv"
- Configured Eclipse to see libraries cv210, highgui210, ml210, cxcore210
- Configured Eclipse to see library folder "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib"

I then took a test source code from the Samples folder (lkdemo.c), put it in my source folder, and built the source (Project-->Build All).

The build is successful, and I see a Test.exe (called my project Test). However, when I try to run the exe file, I get the error:

> The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

What did I miss? I may be mistaken, but I thought MinGW was the gcc compiler?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need Eclipse, Visual Studio, and Mingw?

Comment: Read this,
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?action=printpage;topic=11313.0

Answer (score 0):

First you probably want to download the opencv2.1 src for eclipse/mingw not the vs-2008 libs.

"libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" means it can't find that dll at runtime, it needs to be on the path.
I'm guessing from the name that it's part of mingw/gcc install?
Do a search of the C: drive for this file.

Comment: My only other option is to compile from source, there was no pre-compiled package for eclipse/mingw. But from what I can see on the readme that came with the vs-2008 install file, I can use eclipse/mingw as long as I set the paths right. 

I found the dll under ..\MinGW\bin after a search. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the folder which contains dll files to the system path

> My computer->Environment variable

restart the computer and then try to re-execute the application.